# How to get the size of database in KB/MB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Android application in **Ionic** where I put a pre-populated database in apk. User can insert and delete records and initially the size of DB file is 217kb . I want to track after some time what is the current DB file size on user's device.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use :

```
// "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
// OR
String path=context.getDatabasePath(DataBaseHelper.dbName).toString;

File file = new File(path);
long length = file.length(); // File size
```

Answer (score 0):

you may get it using this:

```
// Get file from file name
File file = new File("path to your file");

// Get length of file in bytes
long fileSizeInBytes = file.length();
// Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
// Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
```